# Calling a function inside same class not working, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to typescript and I am having a problem with calling a function inside the same class:
I have a function like this:

```
createPost(url: String, data: any) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url + "/" + GLOBAL.REGISTER_URL,
      type: "POST",
      data: data.serialize(),
      success: function() {
        console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

And I am trying to call it here:

```
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        $('#success_message').slideDown("slow"); // Do something ...
        $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // XXX reassigning port for testing purposes only
        var result = "https://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + GLOBAL.PORT + "/" + GLOBAL.VERSION + "/rest" + GLOBAL.REGISTER_URL;

        this.createPost(result, $form);
      });
```

But this is not working, every time when I click the button, I got a error in the browser:

> ERROR TypeError: this.createPost is not a function Stack trace:
>   ../../../../../src/app/register/register.component.ts/RegisterComponent.prototype.ngOnInit/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:839:13
>   dispatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10263
>   add/q.handle@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8325
>   trigger@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:5806
>   trigger/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:6310
>   each@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:2813
>   each@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:1001
>   trigger@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:6289
>   _submit@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/bootstrapValidator.js:549:13
>   validate@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/bootstrapValidator.js:857:13
>   _init/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/bootstrapValidator.js:109:21
>   dispatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10263
>   add/q.handle@http://localhost:4200/assets/js-lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8325
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2839:17
>   onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49785:24
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2838:17
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2606:28
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2913:24
>   invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3785:9
>   globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3803:17

This should be a simple function call, and I don't know what is going on, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Is that... jQuery ?

Comment: Where is _"here"_ that you're calling it, exactly? Can you show your whole class?

Comment: Where is the class you're referring to?

Comment: function() is changing the scope of this. try using the arrow function (e)=>{this.createPost(result, $form)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is for the scope.. what i can suggest to you is to try something like:

```
.on('success.form.bv',(e) => { //<-- use arrow func
        $('#success_message').slideDown("slow"); // Do something ...
        $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // XXX reassigning port for testing purposes only
        var result = "https://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + GLOBAL.PORT + "/" + GLOBAL.VERSION + "/rest" + GLOBAL.REGISTER_URL;

        this.createPost(result, $form);
      });
```

OR WRAP your this like:

```
var _that = this;
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        $('#success_message').slideDown("slow"); // Do something ...
        $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // XXX reassigning port for testing purposes only
        var result = "https://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + GLOBAL.PORT + "/" + GLOBAL.VERSION + "/rest" + GLOBAL.REGISTER_URL;

        _that.createPost(result, $form);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `function {}` with TypeScript. Instead use `() => {}` so that the `this` reference is kept valid.

Otherwise you have to use `(function() {}).bind(this)` to keep `this`.

```
  .on('success.form.bv', (e) => {
    // ......
    this.createPost(result, $form);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the problem because of closures. Normally Typescript and Angular work to make this a rare issue, but....you're using jQuery?

To fix:

change

```
createPost(url: String, data: any) {...}
```

to

```
createPost = (url: String, data: any) => {...}
```

The fat arrow or lambda function creates a lexical *this* which doesn't change scope.

...On a side note, why use jQuery with Angular 2+? Angular already does so much to capture and expose the DOM API, it seems like shooting yourself in the foot 
 and purposefully overcomplicating things by subverting that with jQuery. Angular does enough to make jQuery completely unnecessary.

Comment: We are converting a previous project to angular framework, and we are using jquery before.